# Google chrome to notify linux console of a specific event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console-application

Have a look at the following script, that is executed in a linux console:

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=/data --app=http://greensock.com/gsap &
ffmpeg -s 640x360 -f x11grab -i :0+100,100 -y capture.mkv &
```

The idea is that I start google chrome with a url that will play a animation. I use ffmpeg to record the animation.

All good so far, but I have a syncronization problem.

I want to notify the "console" somehow that "the animation is ready" and THEN start **ffmpeg** to start recording. The "ready" event will be then built in in the animation Javascript code.

Any ideas how can I achieve that?

I am thinking using ***--remote-debugging-port*** but not sure how.

Comment: surely the command after `ffmpeg` is hit once `ffmpeg` has completed the task, or do you mean the page load from chrome ?

Comment: I mean after the page load from chrome. It's a bit more complex: page load, prepare animation and execute it...